# Why this C program of prime number is wrong?

Tags: c, primes

Please help ! Why this Prime number Program in C is not working ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=2;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        printf("%d is not a prime number",n);
        else
        printf("%d is a prime number",n);

    }

    getch();
}
```

Please answer-- Why This program is not working ??

Comment: _Why This program is not working..._ What exactly is not working?

Comment: Hint: you should decide whether the number is prime AFTER testing all possible divisors. Also, it's useless to test divisors up to n-1 as @flaviodesousa points out.

Comment: In fact divisors > sqrt(n) are useless

Comment: as well as even divisors > 2

Comment: This program showing no response. I know prime number is divisible by 1 and self. Why should I check ? I only check number between 2 to number is divisible or not? Am i right?

Comment: @Ashutosh The program is showing no response because neither of your `printf`s have `\n` on the end of the format string. This means the internal buffer for the file is never flushed.

Comment: "Not working" is different than "not efficient" - the suggestions made would make the program _better_ but they are not _errors_.  If you are getting bad (or no) output then something else is wrong.  First make the program _work_, then focus on making it _better_.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag to check whether the number is divisible or not?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()

{
    int n,i,flag=0;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=2;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
     }

    if ( flag == 1 )
    {
        printf("%d is not a prime number",n);
    }
    else
    {
     printf("%d is a prime number",n);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Also, the for loop: `for(i=2;i<=n-1;i++)` iterates more than required. You should set `i <= sqrt(n)`.

Comment: `i <= sqrt(n)` or that makes perfect squares prime.

Comment: I would use `i * i <= n` to avoid using the `sqrt()` function

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Also, your `printf`s need `\n`s at the end of the format string

Comment: @JeremyP Is that necessary? That will insert a newline, nothing much.

Comment: Minor: A flag called `is_prime` is more descriptive that a flag called `flag`.

Comment: what is use of flag @learner

Comment: `printf("%d is %s a prime number",n,flag ? "" : "not");` :)

Comment: @learner You need the `\n` so that the command line prompt will start on a new line, more importantly, without it, the buffer for stdout will not be flushed, and so the output might not appear at all.

Comment: @Ashutosh A number is a prime number if that's divisible by any number excluding 1. The flag keeps track of the fact that whether the number is divisible. Also, I break from loop to ensure that the loop doesn't run more times.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's awesome. :)